# Why does my JavaScript file crash without any apparent errors?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation

```js
function validate() {
  var errMsg = "";
  var result = true;

  var fname = document.getElementById("fname").value;
   if (!fname.match(/^[a-zA-Z]+$/)) {
        errMsg += "Please enter your first name correctly.\n";
        result = false;
    }
  var lname = document.getElementById("lname").value;
    if (!lname.match(/^[a-zA-Z]+$/)) {
        errMsg += "Please enter your last name correctly.\n";
        result = false;
    }
  var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
    if (!email.match(/[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,}$/)) {
        errMsg += "Please enter your email correctly.\n";
        result = false;
    }
  var streetname = document.getElementById("streetname").value;
    if (!streetname.match(/^[a-zA-Z0-9\s]+$/)) {
        errMsg += "Please enter your street name correctly.\n";
        result = false;
    }
    var suburb = document.getElementById("suburb").value;
    if (!suburb.match(/^[a-zA-Z\-]+$/)) {
        errMsg += "Please enter your suburb correctly.\n";
        result = false;
    }
    var phone = document.getElementById("phone").value;
  if (!phone.match(/[0-9]{9}/)) {
        errMsg += "Please enter your phone number correctly.\n";
        result = false;
    }


  var postcode = document.getElementById("postcode").value;
  var state = document.getElementById("state").options[
document.getElementById("state").selectedIndex
  ].text;

  var regex;
  //VIC = 3 OR 8, NSW = 1 OR 2 ,QLD = 4 OR 9 ,NT = 0 ,WA = 6 ,SA=5 ,TAS=7 ,ACT= 0.
  switch (state) {
case "Please Select":
  return false;
case "VIC":
  regex = new RegExp(/(3|8)\d+/);
  break;
case "NSW":
  regex = new RegExp(/(1|2)\d+/);
  break;
case "QLD":
  regex = new RegExp(/(4|9)\d+/);
  break;
case "NT":
  regex = new RegExp(/0\d+/);
  break;
case "WA":
  regex = new RegExp(/6\d+/);
  break;
case "SA":
  regex = new RegExp(/5\d+/);
  break;
case "TAS":
  regex = new RegExp(/7\d+/);
  break;
case "ACT":
  regex = new RegExp(/0\d+/);
  break;
  }
  if (!postcode.match(regex)) {
errMsg = errMsg + "State and postcode do not match\n";
result = false;
  }

  if (errMsg) {
alert(errMsg);
  }

  if (result) {
storeBooking(
  fname,
  lname,
  email,
  phone,
  streetname,
  suburb,
  state,
  postcode
);
  }
  return result;
}

function storeBooking(
  fname,
  lname,
  email,
  phone,
  streetname,
  suburb,
  state,
  postcode
) {
  sessionStorage.fname = fname;
  sessionStorage.lname = lname;
  sessionStorage.email = email;
  sessionStorage.phone = phone;
  sessionStorage.streetname = streetname;
  sessionStorage.suburb = suburb;
  sessionStorage.state = state;
  sessionStorage.postcode = postcode;
}



function init() {
  var regForm = document.getElementById("regform");

  regForm.onsubmit = validate;
}

window.onload = init;

window.onload = function() {
  var date = new Date();
  var dd = date.getDate();
  var mm = date.getMonth() + 1;
  var yyyy = date.getFullYear();

  //Add a zero if one Digit (eg: 05,09)
  if (dd < 10) {
    dd = "0" + dd;
  }

  //Add a zero if one Digit (eg: 05,09)
  if (mm < 10) {
    mm = "0" + mm;
  }

  minYear = yyyy - 80; //Calculate Minimun Age (<80)
  maxYear = yyyy - 15; //Calculate Maximum Age (>18)

  var min = minYear + "-" + mm + "-" + dd;
  var max = maxYear + "-" + mm + "-" + dd;

  document.getElementById("start").setAttribute("min", min);
  document.getElementById("start").setAttribute("max", max);
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <script src="scripts/part2.js"></script>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>SwinTech</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
  </head>
  <body class="applypage">
    <header>
      <div class="main">
        <div class="logo">
          <img src="logo.png" alt="logo">
        </div>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <a href="index.html">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="jobs.html">Jobs</a>
          </li>
          <li class="active">
            <a href="apply.html">Apply</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="about.html">About</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </header>
  <section class="applything"><h2>Job application:</h2>
    <br>
    <div class="containerr">
      <form action="https://mercury.swin.edu.au/it000000/formtest.php" method="post" id="regform">


        <label>Job Reference Number</label>
        <input type="text" id="onlyletters" name="onlyletters" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9]+" minlength="5" maxlength="5" placeholder="Reference number for specified job.." required="required">
        <label for="fname">First Name</label>
        <input type="text" id="fname" name="firstname" placeholder="Your name.." required="required" maxlength="25" onkeypress="return (event.charCode > 64 && event.charCode < 91) || (event.charCode > 96 && event.charCode < 123) || (event.charCode==32)">
        <label for="lname">Last Name</label>
        <input type="text" id="lname" name="lastname" placeholder="Your last name.." required="required" onkeypress="return (event.charCode > 64 && event.charCode < 91) || (event.charCode > 96 && event.charCode < 123) || (event.charCode==32)">

   <label for="start">Date of birth:</label>
    <input type="date" id="start" required="required" name="trip-start" value="2021-10-02" />
        <br>
        <br>
        <label for="gender"> Select you gender</label>
        <br>
        <br>
        <select name="gender" id="gender" required="required">
          <option value="" selected>Please Select</option>
          <option value="male">Male</option>
          <option value="female">Female</option>
        </select>
        <br>
        <label for="streetname">Street Address</label>
        <input type="text" id="streetname" name="streetname" required="required" placeholder="Your street name..." maxlength="40" />
        <label for="suburb">Suburb/Town</label>
        <input type="text" id="suburb" name="suburb" required="required" placeholder="Your suburb/town..." maxlength="40">
        <label for="state">Choose a state:</label>
        <br>
        <select name="state" id="state" required="required">
          <option value="">Please Select</option>
          <option value="VIC">VIC</option>
          <option value="NSW">NSW</option>
          <option value="QLD">QLD</option>
          <option value="NT">NT</option>
          <option value="WA">WA</option>
          <option value="SA">SA</option>
          <option value="TAS">TAS</option>
          <option value="ACT">ACT</option>
        </select>
        <br>
        <br>
        <label for="postcode">Postcode</label>
        <input type="text" id="postcode" name="postcode" required="required" placeholder="Your postcode..." maxlength="4" minlength="4" pattern="^[0-9]{4}$">
        <label for="email">Email Address</label>
        <input type="text" id="email" name="emailadd" placeholder="Your email address.." required="required">
        <label for="phone">Phone Number</label>
        <input type="text" id="phone" name="phonenumb" placeholder="e.g. 0451124561" minlength="8" maxlength="12" required="required">
        <br>
        <label>Skills</label>
        <br>
        <br>
        <input type="checkbox" id="skill1" name="skill1" value="Javascript">
        <label for="skill1"> Extensive knowledge of Javascript</label>
        <br>
        <br>
        <input type="checkbox" id="skill2" name="skill2" value="Python">
        <label for="skill2"> Extensive knowledge of Python</label>
        <br>
        <br>
        <input type="checkbox" id="skill3" name="skill3" value="C#">
        <label for="skill3"> Extensive knowledge of Networking</label>
        <br>
        <br>
        <input type="checkbox" id="skill4" name="skill4" value="C#">
        <label for="skill4"> Extensive knowledge of Data storage fundamentals</label>
        <br>
        <br>
        <input type="checkbox" id="skill5" name="skill5" value="C#">
        <label for="skill5"> Extensive knowledge of Security foundations</label>
        <br>
        <br>
        <input type="checkbox" id="skill6" name="skill6" value="C#">
        <label for="skill6"> Extensive knowledge of AWS service selection</label>
        <br>
        <br>
        <input type="checkbox" id="skill7" name="skill7" value="C#">
        <label for="skill7"> Ability to work in a team</label>
        <br>
        <br>
        <input type="checkbox" id="skill8" name="skill8" value="C#">
        <label for="skill8"> 5+ years experience</label>
        <br>
        <br>
        <input type="checkbox" id="skill9" name="skill9" value="C#">
        <label for="skill9"> 10+ years experience</label>
        <br>
        <br>
        <input type="checkbox" id="skill10" name="skill10" value="C#">
        <label for="skill10"> 20+ years experience</label>
        <br>
        <br>
        <input
    type="checkbox"
    id="other"
    name="other"
    value="other"
    onclick="otherCheckBox()"
  />
        <label for="other"> I have other skills. Please list other skills below.</label>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <label for="subject">Subject:</label>
        <textarea id="otherbox" name="subject" placeholder="textarea" style="height:200px"></textarea>
        <input type="submit" value="Apply">
      </form>
    </div>
  </section>
  <div class="footer">
    <div class="footer-content"></div>
    <div class="footer-bottom"></div> &copy; swintech.com | Designed by Bilal El-leissy
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

My JavaScript crashes even though there are no apparent errors when I check the console on Chrome. I've tried rearranging and removing certain functions from the JavaScript but there doesn't seem to be a particular pattern so I cannot determine which piece of code is crashing the rest of it.

What specifically happens is that all my validation stops working except my date of birth validation.

Note: Cannot use inline JavaScript or jQuery.

Comment: How exactly does Your JS crashes?
I didn't find any problem with the code running in jsfiddle

Comment: @PavloStepura The only thing that validates is the date of birth, which makes it so that you can only input a date which would make you between 15-80 years old at the time of entering the form. My other ones, like my function to make sure your name doesn't include numbers, your phone number is all numbers and the state and postcode match each other, do not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank You for clarifying.

The problem is with `init()` method.

```
function init() {
  var regForm = document.getElementById("regform");

  regForm.onsubmit = validate;
}

window.onload = init;

window.onload = function() {
  var date = new Date();
  var dd = date.getDate();
```

In this piece of code `window.onload = init;` You assign init function to window.onload and after that immediately reassign `window.onload` with `function() {..}`

So Your init() function is never called.
Try to move init function call like this:

```
window.onload = function() {
  init();
  var date = new Date();
  var dd = date.getDate();
  var mm = date.getMonth() + 1;
 ... }
```